# Using #define constants in enumurated data types, syntax error

Tags: visual-c++, enums, mfc, c-preprocessor

I am a bit puzzled by this error I get while trying to compile my MFC project. To simplify, I wish to enumerate something like this:

```
enum Cars
{
Audi,
Bmw,
Ford
};
```

Which works fine, but I get errors while compiling when I define any of the 'Cars' such as in:

```
#define Audi 100
...
...
enum Cars
{
    Audi,
    BMW,
    Ford
};
```

The errors I get are, both in the header I wrote this and the source file

> error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before 'constant'
>
> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
>
> error C2059: syntax error : '}'

I don't know why I get a syntax error because both parts compile fine separately. I know that I can easily just define Audi =100 in the enum definition, but in my actual project I can't to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a define it's like doing a search and replace for that text and then the compiling takes place, so for your example you now have Audi becoming 100 so your enum looks like

```
enum Cars
{
    100,
    BMW,
    Ford
};
```

Since 100 is not a valid enum name you are seeing this error.

If you want Audio to be value 100 you can do

```
enum Cars
{
    Audi = 100,
    BMW,
    Ford
};
```

Although be careful when doing this as BMW and Ford now have their values set to 101,102 respectively so you need to ensure you do a full recompile if this was in a header file.

Answer (score -2):

I prefer to leave macros and use the following feature of C++11.
    enum class Cars { AUDI = 100, BMW, FORD };

Comment: You have taken a C++11 feature and turned it into a non-feature. If you use an `enum class` the enumerators do not implicitly convert to integers. As such, the assigned values are of no interest. If you want to explicitly assign integer values to enumerators use a simple `enum` instead.